# How to ensure pointers don't point to the same place

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Running the following code, it get 57 57 printed out, what I need is 56 57. I know this is because the pointers are pointing to the same location, but how do I avoid this?

```
int (*spriteArray[10])[8][8];
int i = 0;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

someOtherMethod();
i++;
someOtherMethod();

someMethod();

  delay(100000);
}

void someOtherMethod()
{
    int sprite[8][8];
    spriteArray[i]= &sprite;

    sprite[0][0] = 56+i;

}
void someMethod()
{

  Serial.println(*spriteArray[0][0][0]);   
  Serial.println(*spriteArray[1][0][0]); 

}
```

Answer (score 8):

In `someOtherMethod` you store a pointer to a local variable, and that pointer is not valid after the function returns. Dereferencing this pointer causes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: so what would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: @user1608058 You might want to rethink your design. Otherwise you could do a simple copy of the arrays, using a couple of nested `for` loops.